# Testing Keystone and Mongoose with Jest

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs, keystonejs

I am implementing unit testing in a project with [Keystone](https://keystonejs.com/) but it always throws an error at testing:

```
an all test suites.
/Project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:433
      throw err
      ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
at /Project/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/start.js:64:44
at /Project/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24
at eachOfArrayLike (/Project/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1069:9)
at eachOf (/Project/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1117:5)
at _parallel (/Project/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3879:5)
at Object.parallelLimit [as parallel] (/Project/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3962:5)
at /Project/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/start.js:60:9
at connected (/Project/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:78:5)
at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Project/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:85:4)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:182:13)
at /Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:860:13
at connectCallback (/Project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:527:5)
at /Project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:430:11
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I already tried using "import { init, start, mongoose } from 'keystone';" instead, and using jest async() and await. I run too "jest --clearCache". Jest version: "jest": "^24.3.1"

My .babelrc:

```
{
"presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env",
        {"targets": {
            "node": "current"
        }}
    ], 
    "@babel/preset-react"
]    
}
```

test.js:

```
const Keystone = require('keystone');

beforeAll( done => {
    Keystone.init({
        'name': 'Keystone CMS',
        'cookie secret': 'My_Biscuit',
    });
    Keystone.start();
    done();
})

describe('Test Keystone CMS own features', () => {
    test('Keystone connects to MongoDB', (done) => {
        expect(Keystone.mongoose.connections._listening).toBeTruthy;
        done();
    });
});
```

I will then expand it to test mongoose

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that it is not really possible at the moment:
https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/3564